# How to display a react-notification after redirect to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, notifications

I have a Signup page developed with ReactJS and I want after the click of submit button, it redirects me to login page, after that it display a react-notification which message is `response.data.message`.

I used `react-notifications-component` :

```
import ReactNotification from "react-notifications-component";
export default class Signup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addNotification = this.addNotification.bind(this);
    this.notificationDOMRef = React.createRef();
  }
 addNotification(message) {
    this.notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification( {
      title: "Awesomeness",
      message:{message},
      type: "success",
      insert: "top",
      container: "top-right",
      animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],
      animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],
      dismiss: { duration: 2000 },
      dismissable: { click: true }
    });

  }

 handleSubmit =  event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const users = {
      name:this.state.name,
      email:this.state.email,
    }
    console.log(users)
   const { history } = this.props
   axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://172.16.234.24:8000/api/register',
    data: users,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
    })
    .then(function (response) {

         try{
      console.log(response);
      console.log('yes');
      history.push('/login');
      this.addNotification(response.data.message);
             }
        catch{
      console.log('no');
            }

    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

  }
<Button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Register </Button>
          <ReactNotification ref={this.notificationDOMRef} />
```

When I run it, it redirects me to the login page and the notification not working and I get `no` in the console of `catch`.

How can I fix that or have you a suggestion to use another system for notifications ?

Comment: Pass an error into the catch and output the error. It will probably give you a better understanding of what is going wrong. `try { ... } catch(error) { console.log(error); }`

Comment: @JLeggatt the error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addNotification' of undefined`

Comment: Ah, so your `this` reference has lost reference. This is because the anonymous function doesn't know what `addNotification` refers to. Try adding a `.bind` to the inline function that then calls.

Comment: I have already  `this.addNotification = this.addNotification.bind(this);` in my constructor

Comment: The problem is that you're using the `this` keyword inside the anonymous function the `then` calls. If you console log `this` above the `this.addNotification` you'll see it doesn't have access to the `this.addNotification`

Comment: `console.log(this)` is `undefined` so how can I call this function inside `then` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to bind this, you should use arrow functions

```
.then(response => {
    try{
      console.log(response);
      console.log('yes');
      history.push('/login');
      this.addNotification(response.data.message);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log('no');
    }
});
```

Comment: it is still the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, an arrow function would also bind this. However, I didn't know if he would understand an arrow function so I thought I'd recommend using a manual bind.

Comment: @CodeLover, maybe the addNotification will be out of context after the push. try to run first this.addNotification, and after the history.push, using that format of then (with arrow function)